# Remove all panels but retaining widget functionalities in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, panel, volume-control

I would like to remove all panels from Kubuntu 16.04.

This is pretty easily done by right-clicking on the default panel and removing, but it seems that some of the functionality of KDE is removed with it. Namely, the volume controls and application dashboard hotkeys (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) no longer work.

Is there some way to remove all panels but retain these volume/launcher capabilities?

Or alternatively, is there a way to permanently hide the default panel? Auto-hide is ok, but I would prefer it to not pop-up when my cursor is at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot. Because the application dashboards are not independent, instead they are dependent on their parent widget, which was the panel. Since it's removed, your application launcher or dashboard is also removed.

However, if you really want to get rid of the panel, you can do this instead.

1. Remove the panel.
2. Add the required widgets to the desktop. You can do so, because these widgets can be added on desktop too!
3. Once added, press and hold the click to get the settings/preference window of the widget. There you can set a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

You should be able to use the widget now. Repeat the process for all the other widgets you use.

There will be one problem still and that is the icons of these widgets will stay on the desktop. But you can resize them and arrange them so that they look like native to your setup.

Hope that helps

---

Following user requirement, it seems recently a dock is appearing for KDE named [Latte-Dock](https://github.com/psifidotos/Latte-Dock). The deb package provided in the github repository needs QT 5.7, which is difficult to grab in Kubuntu 16.04. But fortunately some people from [mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=243876) figured out that it can be built using QT 5.6 easily. I tested it and indeed it is. Follow the instruction on the forum post.

Here is a screenshot of running only a dock in KDE5.

[image: only a dock screenshot]

Comment: Anwar, thank you for this helpful comment. I have added the Application Dashboard widget and have minimized it to a corner of the screen as a temporary solution. Ultimately, I would like to only have a dock (such as Plank) on my desktop. To your knowledge, is there some dock that would support a Launcher functionality? Or is there even some way to add a widget to a dock?

Comment: You mean kde widgets like the application menus in a dock?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: @user682514 You can try Latte Dock. But it's still under development and may need to be built from source. Check out [this omgubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/kde-latte-dock-replace-plasma-panel) and [kde.store download source](https://store.kde.org/p/1169519/).

Comment: @user682514 hi, I've updated the answer with most easy option to build the dock.